# Text box value are not accessing in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a textbox on .aspx page..On this page there is a user control .Inside this user contrl there is a button .I want o get the value of text box on button click which is not inside the user control .How can i do this

Please Help me .

Comment: What do you get when you say `this.Page` in the `UserControl` ?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want....

Answer (score 2):

write this line in you button click event of user control

```
protected void Button_Click(sender obj,EventArgs arg)
{
  TextBox txtbox= (((MyPage)parent).FindControl("TextBoxid") as TextBox);
  if(txtbox!=null)
   (((MyPage)this.Page).FindControl("TextBoxid") as TextBox).Text;
  //or 
  //(((MyPage)this.Parent).FindControl("TextBoxid") as TextBox).Text;

}
```

**or**

alternative is create the property in your page and access it in your user control

```
public string txtValue
{
  get 
  {
    return TextboxID.Text;
  }
}
```

in button click event of user control

```
protected void Button_Click(sender obj,EventArgs arg)
{
    string txtvalue = ((Mypage)this.Page).txtValue;
   //or
   //((MyPage)this.Parent).txtValue;

}
```

Comment: Don't you have to cast FindControl to TextBox to get Text property? `((TextBox)((MyPage)parent).FindControl("TextBoxid")).Text`

Answer (score 0):

```
((TextBox)USerControl.Page.FindControl("txtbox")).Text
```

or

```
((YourPageType)USerControl.Page).TextBox.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string TextBoxValue;
  TextBoxValue = MyTextBox.Text;
}
```

Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following method,

```
((TextBox)USerControl.Parent.FindControl("txtbox")).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

With de-coupling in mind, I would recommend that if your user control needs to access information outside of it, then that information should passed in, not vice versa. The control shouldn't be responsible for where the information comes from, it just knows there is information. With this in mind, I would recommend bubbling the event to get the required information.

## Event Bubbling

This will involve creating a new delegate, and then triggering it once the `Button` has been clicked, thus bubbling the event and allowing us to return the desired value, which in this case is the textbox value.

### Step 1: Declare the delegate

```
// declare a delegate
public delegate string MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

### Step 2: Update the user control

```
// update the user control
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // add the delegate property to your user control
    public event MyEventHandler OnSomeButtonPressed;

    // trigger the event when the button is pressed
    protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string someString = string.Empty;
        if (this.OnSomeButtonPressed != null)
        {
            someString = this.OnSomeButtonPressed(this, e);
        }

        // do something with the string
    }    
}
```

### Step 3: Update the page

```
// be sure to register the event in the page!
public class MyPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(sender, e);
        myUserControl.OnSomeButtonPressed += this.HandleUserControl_ButtonClick;
    }

    public string HandleUserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return this.SomeTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```